# Limit of a product of two functions with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose the functions $f$ and $g$ have the following property: for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all x :

if $0 < |x-2| < \sin^2(\frac{\epsilon ^2}{9}) + \epsilon \Rightarrow |f(x) - 2| < \epsilon$ and if $0 < |x-2| <\epsilon ^2 \Rightarrow |g(x) - 4| < \epsilon$.

For each $\epsilon > 0$, find a $\delta > 0$ such that:

if $0 < |x-2| < \delta$ then $|f(x)g(x) - 8|<  \epsilon$

Attempt: I was trying to manipulate the expression $|f(x)g(x) - 8|$ with the hope of getting it into the form $|f(x) - 2||g(x) - 4|$ where I could draw some conclusions from the given statements, but I was unsuccessful in these attempts. I saw the solution and it states:

we need:  $$|f(x) - 2| < \min \left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{2(|4| + 1)}\right)$$ and $$|g(x) - 4| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(|2| + 1)}$$

And from this we're able to draw a conclusion on $\delta$. My question is how did they go about obtaining these values and the train of thought used to conclude this? I've been doing delta-epsilon proofs for ahwile and never saw this process before.

**Edit**  Ok I've been working on it and I almost have the solution I believe:

I was hinted to bound g(x), so attempting that:

$$\text{let } |g(x) - 4| < 4 \Rightarrow 0 < g(x) < 8$$

Therefore: $$|8||f(x) - 2| + |2||g(x) - 4| = \\ |4||f(x)-2| + |g(x) -4| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

I can see how $(|4| + 1)$ can come about, but in order for that to occur, I would have needed $|g(x) - 4| = |f(x) - 2|$.....suggesstions?

Comment: Your title should not be the first line of your question - please always use an explicit title that describes the content of the question. It makes it more useful in searching and for future use.

Comment: For the symbol $\Rightarrow$ of implication, use the Latex command \Rightarrow.

Comment: Maybe you can use that
$$f(x)g(x)-8=(f(x)-2)(g(x)-4)+4(f(x)-2)+2(g(x)-4)$$

Comment: @Kelenner how can you use that? the two "(-8)" terms give (-16). Every other term I see coming about because you are adding zero.

Comment: The first product is $(-2)(-4)=+8$ (in $(f(x)-2)(g(x)-4)$). The two others gives $-16$, and hence the constant term is $-8$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$f(x)g(x)-8=f(x)g(x)-2g(x)+2g(x)-8=(f(x)-2)g(x)+2(g(x)-4).$$

Then use triangle inequality and you may want to bound $|g(x)|$ from above using the fact that the limit of $g$ is 4.

Comment: Curses, I had tried $4f(x)$ as the adding zero term to the inequality. This is a question how do you know or is there a systematic way of determining what to combine to create a "zero term"? and also, How do you know the limit of g(x) is 4? and not sure on how to bound this from above, use just 1?

Comment: This would also be ok with $4f(x)$ instead of $2g(x)$. The limit of g(x) is 4 simply using what you wrote at the beginning for g...